# Иерархия постов в WordPress (вложенность постов)

Tags: wordpress

В самом ядре WordPress есть функция

```
function create_initial_post_types() {
register_post_type(
    'post',
    array(
        'labels'                => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new from admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public'                => true,
        '_builtin'              => true, /* internal use only. don't use this when registering your own post type. */
        '_edit_link'            => 'post.php?post=%d', /* internal use only. don't use this when registering your own post type. */
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'rewrite'               => false,
        'query_var'             => false,
        'delete_with_user'      => true,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'rest_base'             => 'posts',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
    )
);
```

Мне нужно сделать поддержку иерархии для записей, если изменить параметр hierarchical на true и в supports добавить 'page-attributes' то все работает. Но при обновлении такие настройки слетят. Как можно сделать тоже самое только что настройки не слетели при обновлении wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

В файл functions.php вашей темы нужно добавить

```
// Add page attributes for posts
    add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );

    function change_register_post_type_args ( $args, $post_type ) {
        if ( 'post' === $post_type ) {
            $args['hierarchical'] = true;
        }

        return $args;
    }
    add_post_type_support('post', array('page-attributes') );
```